# Oracle Apex submit when 'enter' pressed

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an text field in an oracle apex form. A user can type in a search query and hit the "Search" button to submit the page. I also want to allow the user to just be able to hit the enter key to search.

On the text field I have the option "Submit when Enter Pressed" set to Yes. However this is not working. I think it is because I have other processes attached to other buttons on the page that are used to also submit the form for other purposes.

My question is, is there anyway to define specifically what process gets called when enter is pressed from a specific text field?

Answer (score 6):

When you submit a page by pressing Enter in an item with "Submit when Enter pressed" set to Yes, the page is submitted with the Request value set to the name of the item.  You can therefore make the process conditional on the value of Request being the item name.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do the same with a 'text autocomplete' field in APEX?